# Elasticsearch php giving error when setting 2 criterias in must clause

Tags: php, mongodb, elasticsearch

I am trying to add multiple criterion to ElasticSearch PHP in must clause, but it is giving me a 500 Error.

My params are:

```
 $params = ['index' => 'smartjn',
    'type' => 'feed_details',
    'size' => 10,
    'body' => [
        'sort' => [
            'sorter' => [
                'order' => 'desc',
                'mode' => 'max'
            ]
        ],
        'query' => ['bool' => [
                'must' => [
                    ['match' => ['approvalStatus' => 'approved']],
                    [ '_id' => [
                            '$lt' => new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId($documentid)
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
                'must_not' => ['term' => ['muteFeedUserIds' => $userID]],
                'must_not' => ['term' => ['muteUserIds' => $userID]]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

Please note that this works if I remove the second criteria in must clause i.e.

```
 $params = ['index' => 'smartjn',
    'type' => 'feed_details',
    'size' => 10,
    'body' => [
        'sort' => [
            'sorter' => [
                'order' => 'desc',
                'mode' => 'max'
            ]
        ],
        'query' => ['bool' => [
                'must' => [
                    ['match' => ['approvalStatus' => 'approved']]
                ],
                'must_not' => ['term' => ['muteFeedUserIds' => $userID]],
                'must_not' => ['term' => ['muteUserIds' => $userID]]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

Any idea what am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-ids-query.html

Comment: not helping @blackmamba ! could you please be kind enough to correct my params array

Answer (score 0):

check this out.

```
  'query' => ['bool' => [
                    'must' => [
                        ['match' => ['approvalStatus' => 'approved']],
                        [ 'ids' => [
                                'values' => [new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId($documentid)]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ],
                    'must_not' => ['term' => ['muteFeedUserIds' => $userID]],
                    'must_not' => ['term' => ['muteUserIds' => $userID]]
                ]
```

If that doesnt work i am giving you the raw as i am not good with elasticphp

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "ids": {
            "type": "type_of_index"
            "values": ["AVbqtjXfoKQ0pubF_-NA"]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

type is optional
Just add this ids part under must area.